# NOT IN query using an apex collection

Tags: sql, collections, oracle-apex

I have a form with a select list. Before, we were only concerned with the user selecting one survey name, but now we want to store several survey names in a collection.

Also, once the survey name has been selected, it should no longer appear in the list. The query before is as follows:

```
Select survey_name, survey_id  
from SURVEYS
```

Simple list. I have written queries before using NOT IN but they were based on tables. I'm having trouble creating my LOV and incorporating a collection. I have tried the following

```
SELECT survey_name N, survey_id S  
FROM SURVEYS  
where survey_id NOT IN (  
   SELECT ac.c003  
   FROM apex_collections ac  
   WHERE ac.collection_name = 'BENCHMARKS' )
```

I am using a popup LOV and the list is not populating. I'm not sure what to do with this or if it is even possible to do such a query with collections. The collection is being created everytime you go to the page. When you navigate away from the page, it's not expected to save the values.

Any help on this would be greatly appreaciated. Thanks in advace

Comment: Where are you testing this query, in the application pages or in an IDE like SQL Developer/TOAD? How is the collection populated? If you create a report on the APEX page with
`SELECT ac.c003  
   FROM apex_collections ac  
   WHERE ac.collection_name = 'BENCHMARKS'`
 does the report show any data?

Comment: Also: where (what process/display point) is the collection being filled up? What happens with the selected value from the popup lov? Is the lov intended to be reused several times from the same parent page?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that your subquery doesn't return any null values. One null will hose your entire NOT IN logic. It's good practice to always add a "not null" condition to any subquery used like this.

SELECT ac.c003
  FROM apex_collections ac
 WHERE ac.collection_name = 'BENCHMARKS' 
   AND ac.c003 IS NOT NULL